# Why is std::string_view::starts_with(const charT*) not noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++20, string-view

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/starts_with) there are three overloads for `std::basic_string_view<CharT,Traits>::starts_with`:

```cpp
constexpr bool starts_with( basic_string_view sv ) const noexcept; (1)
constexpr bool starts_with( CharT c ) const noexcept; (2)
constexpr bool starts_with( const CharT* s ) const; (3)
```

Why is the third one not marked as `noexcept`? Similar with `std::basic_string_view<CharT,Traits>::ends_with`

Comment: Third one might fail (UB) for non-nul terminate C-String, allowing exception?

Comment: Interesting, the MS implementation is `noexcept` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/basic-string-view-class?view=msvc-170#starts_with

Comment: @Sean Implementations are allowed to add `noexcept` even if the standard doesn't require it (assuming the function is not specified to throw exceptions): https://eel.is/c++draft/library#res.on.exception.handling-5

Comment: @AdrianMole There's a constructor of `std::string_view` that performs dynamic allocation or performs a copy? I hope not.

Comment: @MatG Luckily, no. There are however constructors that are potentially throwing, presumably for same reason as this function is (and the reason isn't allocation).

Comment: In GCC v11.2, all are `noexcept`. I don't know why it's like that in cppreference.

Comment: @digito_evo Because the standard doesn't require it to be `noexcept`.

Answer (score 0):

Using pointers can potentially result in undefined behavior, that might throw an exception. What e.g. if `s == nullptr` or pointing to something really wrong?

Comment: UB is not equicalent to throwing. UB is not required to throw. UB has nothing to do with throwing. You can have `noexcept` interface that allows UB for an invalid (for some definition of invalid) argument, for example. This answer is wrong.

Comment: @Fureeish However, an implementation is allowed to throw an exception if it detects UB and the lack of `noexcept` makes this easier to implement.

Comment: True, that's why the answer in the duplicate question is complete. OP could extend this answer to introduce the concept of an implementation being allowed to throw custom exceptions, but stating that *UB may equal throwing* is a crucial oversimplification for me.